# Dealing with differently formatted Strings and trying to categorize their data using Java

Tags: java, database, string, substring

I have a column of a spreadsheet that contains data on opening hours for different establishments. Using Java I am trying to store that data in variables (monHours, tuesHours, etc.) but the roadblock I am trying to figure out how to deal with is that there are many different ways each element is formatted. Here are some examples of variations:

"Monday – Friday: 8am – 5pm, Saturday Closed, Sunday Closed"

"Mon 7:15 AM - 4:00 PM, Tue 7:15 AM - 4:00 PM, Wed 7:15 AM - 4:00 PM, Thu 7:15 AM - 4:00 PM, Fri Closed, Sat Closed, Sun Closed"

"Monday 4AM-8PM-Saturday 4AM-8PM, Sunday Closed"

"Mon Closed, Tue Closed, Wed 7 - 9:00 AM, Thu Closed, Fri Closed, Sat 7 - 9:00 AM, Sun Closed"

"24/7"

Again, I am just trying to figure out an algorithm in Java that will take any of those strings and store the opening hours for each day in a variable. I should also note that I can't change the data to one singular format as there are hundreds of entries.

I know that it probably has something to do with string methods, specifically substrings. I have already figured that removing whitespace and commas would probably help, but I am overall struggling to find an algorithm that works for all cases.

##### EDIT

For example if I had an entry of a String like

> "Monday – Friday: 8am – 5pm, Saturday Closed, Sunday Closed"

I would create an array of Strings like

```
["Monday: 8AM-5PM", "Tuesday: 8AM-5PM", "Wednesday: 8AM-5PM", "Thursday: 8AM-5PM", "Friday: 8AM-5PM", "Saturday: closed", "Sunday: closed"].
```

The specific formatting of each element in the array may be different but I imagine you get the idea of how I wish to store it.

Comment: _I am just trying to ... take any of those strings and store the opening hours for each day in a variable_ What is the type of the variable? Is it `String`?

Comment: There are many ways to do so. But, in principle, I would rely on a specific date/time type being returned by a string parsing method dealing with all the input formats. For example, you could stick to days + times and use LocalDateTime. And, in the given parsing method, you would be creating new LocalDateTime variables by looking at both time and the day of week. You can easily account for the different variations via simple conditions. You could have different arrays for opening/closing or even a custom class with a boolean telling whether it is open/close.

Comment: Anything "Human readable" is String (sub parts of charsets is primitive type char, but to use for human reading is String whether one single character or more or in computer terms line breaks and tabs and spaces. See also class Number, and java.time.* package for coherent transfer between human readable and underlying values representational purpose such as math and Date time geography and time measurement and it's human readable formatting. Also watch out for M T W T F S S on lines and NA or  N/A rather than closed.

Comment: @Abra Yes the data type is a string

Comment: Can you post an example value for a variable that you expect to get from a sample value in the spreadsheet?

Comment: @abra For example if I had an entry of a String like "Monday – Friday: 8am – 5pm, Saturday Closed, Sunday Closed", I would create an array of Strings like ["Monday: 8AM-5PM", "Tuesday: 8AM-5PM", "Wednesday: 8AM-5PM", "Thursday: 8AM-5PM", "Friday: 8AM-5PM", "Saturday: closed", "Sunday: closed"]. The specific formatting of each element in the array may be different but I imagine you get the idea of how I wish to store it

Comment: Question details should be in the question itself and not in a comment. I have added your comment to the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's a complex parse.  You can start by delimiting the *strings* on the comma.

```java
String[] strings = {
    "Monday – Friday: 8am – 5pm, Saturday Closed, Sunday Closed",
    "Mon 7:15 AM - 4:00 PM, Tue 7:15 AM - 4:00 PM, Wed 7:15 AM - 4:00 PM, Thu 7:15 AM - 4:00 PM, Fri Closed, Sat Closed, Sun Closed",
    "Monday 4AM-8PM-Saturday 4AM-8PM, Sunday Closed",
    "Mon Closed, Tue Closed, Wed 7 - 9:00 AM, Thu Closed, Fri Closed, Sat 7 - 9:00 AM, Sun Closed",
    "24/7"
};
String[] values;
for (String string : strings) {
    values = string.split(", ");
    for (String value : values) System.out.println(value);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output

```
Monday – Friday: 8am – 5pm
Saturday Closed
Sunday Closed

Mon 7:15 AM - 4:00 PM
Tue 7:15 AM - 4:00 PM
Wed 7:15 AM - 4:00 PM
Thu 7:15 AM - 4:00 PM
Fri Closed
Sat Closed
Sun Closed

Monday 4AM-8PM-Saturday 4AM-8PM
Sunday Closed

Mon Closed
Tue Closed
Wed 7 - 9:00 AM
Thu Closed
Fri Closed
Sat 7 - 9:00 AM
Sun Closed

24/7
```

> *"Again, I am just trying to figure out an algorithm in Java that will take any of those strings and store the opening hours for each day in a variable"*

You can use a *[regular expression pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)*, although I wouldn't recommend it if the format is *too* arbitrary.

For example, this is specific to matching only the formats you've provided.

```
(?i)((sun|mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat)(?:(?:nes|rs|ur)?day)?:? (\d?\d(?::\d\d)?(?: ?[ap]m)?))
```

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)((sun|mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat)(?:(?:nes|rs|ur)?day)?:? (\\d?\\d(?::\\d\\d)?(?: ?[ap]m)?))");
Matcher matcher;
for (String string : strings) {
    matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Output

```
Friday: 8am
Mon 7:15 AM
Tue 7:15 AM
Wed 7:15 AM
Thu 7:15 AM
Monday 4AM
Saturday 4AM
Wed 7
Sat 7
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to implement a method for each of expected formats. Each method would try to parse a string as it formatted in a corresponding way. If the parsing was successful - return the result, otherwise throws an exception (or return null, or whatever you like). Then write as many methods as there are formats you expect and execute them one by one until some method would return successfully parsed value.

Comment: [Chain-of-responsibility pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

Parsing is another issue, but I would create a proper data model to hold your opening times, perhaps something like the below:

```
import java.time.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DaySchedule {
    record FromTo(LocalTime from, LocalTime to) {}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Map<DayOfWeek, List<FromTo>> openingTimes = new HashMap<>();
            // Make mutable List
            openingTimes.put(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, new ArrayList<>(List.of(new FromTo(LocalTime.of(14, 20), LocalTime.of(16,20)))));
            // Add an evening opening period to the short afternoon one
            openingTimes.get(DayOfWeek.MONDAY).add(new FromTo(LocalTime.of(17, 0), LocalTime.of(19, 0)));

            System.out.println(openingTimes);
        }
        catch(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```